# Rails don't redirect to Checkout Stripe Page - Cors problem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, http, https, stripe-payments

I'm trying to implement an integration with the Stripe API, but when I ask Rails to redirect to the checkout URL, the page loads infinitely

This is my code:

**/app/controllers/checkout_controller.rb**

```
class CheckoutController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @stripe_checkout_session = Stripe::Checkout::Session.create(
            payment_method_types: ['card'],
            line_items: [{
                price: 'price_1MZuauECi1aTPXPYEtmpRxAI',
                quantity: 1
            }],
            mode: 'payment',
            success_url: checkout_success_url,
            cancel_url: checkout_cancel_url
        )
        redirect_to @stripe_checkout_session.url, method: :post, allow_other_host: true
    end
end
```

**Loading Page with console log**

[Stripe Checkout Page Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXQ8u.png)

I accessed the terminal where the Rails server is running and copied the link to another page, it worked very well. But with Rails app, it's still not working.

I tried to use form_tag but still not working, what am I doing wrong?

**app/views/checkout/new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag "#{Rails.configuration.stripe[:checkout_base]}/#{@stripe_checkout_session.id}", id: 'checkout-form', method: :post do %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "https://js.stripe.com/v3", "data-stripe": Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>

  <%= hidden_field_tag :sessionId, @stripe_checkout_session.id %>
  <%= submit_tag "Proceed to Checkout" %>
<% end %>
```

**config/initializers/stripe.rb**

```
Stripe.api_key = Rails.application.credentials[:stripe][:secret]

Rails.configuration.stripe = {
  publishable_key: Rails.application.credentials[:stripe][:public],
  secret_key: Rails.application.credentials[:stripe][:secret],
  checkout_base: 'https://checkout.stripe.com/c/pay',
}
```

Yes, my keys are correct.

**Edited**

With the get method, i still get the same error.

[Console Log With Get Method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5KBJ.png)

**###SOLUTION###**

**/app/controllers/checkout_controller.rb**

```
class CheckoutController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @stripe_checkout_session = Stripe::Checkout::Session.create(
            payment_method_types: ['card'],
            line_items: [{
                price: 'price_1MZuauECi1aTPXPYEtmpRxAI',
                quantity: 1
            }],
            mode: 'payment',
            success_url: checkout_success_url,
            cancel_url: checkout_cancel_url
        )
    end
end
```

**app/views/checkout/new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag "#{@stripe_checkout_session.url}", id: 'checkout-form', method: :post do %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "https://js.stripe.com/v3", "data-stripe": Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>

  <%= hidden_field_tag :sessionId, @stripe_checkout_session.id %>
  <%= submit_tag "Proceed to Checkout" %>
<% end %>
```

I was trying mount the link with base url + user id, but this don't work because of cookies. And it doesn't work if you try to redirect directly without the form.

Comment: You cannot redirect with POST. Redirects always result in a GET request.

Comment: @max I'm still having the same problem, I'll edit my answer and add an image with the console log

Comment: Thats wasn't mean to be a solution. Just pointing out a very fundamental problem with this code.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what should happen here, as your controller does `redirect_to` the `url` but your `erb` tries to render the resulting session `id`. Is there a conflict?

Comment: max and Nolan H, I solved my problem, a short explanation was added at the end of the question, thanks.